# WHY: each item's pubDate disappears and RSS contains only one pubDate?

Tags: rss, yahoo, yahoo-pipes, rss-reader

In Yahoo Pipes, when I [view results in the edit pipe window](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=8b5a7df081cdae4253b20022470134ac) each item has its own (different) pubDate.

When I view the [raw output of the RSS in a browser](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=8b5a7df081cdae4253b20022470134ac&_render=rss) pubDate is only present once, in the head.

**Why is that?**

Comment: ugggh... looks like a bug :( Interestingly, if you look at the JSON output it shows `pubDate: null` for all entries...